# All USB devices stop working for a few seconds

Tags: windows-8, usb

For some reason, all of the USB devices that are connected to my desktop computer will spontaneously and simultaneously stop working for a few seconds. Essentially, it's as if they've all been unplugged at the same time, and then plugged in a few seconds later, Windows USB (dis)connect sound effects and all.

The devices that are plugged in are my mouse and keyboard, a USB microphone, the USB power cord for my headset, my external HDD, a USB hub that is used only for easy i/o access to flash drives, and my USB wireless adapter.

I can't reliably reproduce the problem, but I've noticed that it likes to happen whenever I put a bit more stress on the wireless adapter than normal - i.e. if I try to FTP quite a few files to a webserver on the same network or if I try to upload/download a bunch of files at once instead of queuing them.

Comment: strange that using more bandwidth or even power on one usb could affect others in some way, as they're meant to be separate. But try an external powered usb hub maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the increased load over-draws the power that can be delivered by the USB ports.
In many computers these days there is just a single controller chip that drives all USB ports.
If you got a power issue somewhere the device will probably reset. This in turn may cause Windows to reset ALL usb devices on the same controller chip.
And thus the pling/plong concerto starts.

Try a self-powered USB hub en plug as much devices (the ones that don't have own power supplies) as possible into that. The Wifi adapter is the first candidate. That USB harddrive another.

(Are those files being copied by chance coming from/going to that USB harddrive? That would make matters worse.
And if your Wifi signal strength is low the adapter will have to use more power in trying to reach the access-point. So being far from the AP might make it worse too.)

Comment: I'll definitely give this a try, as soon as I can I'll get a self-powered hub. And I have a few walls between me and the AP but I usually get a solid 5 bars' connection to the network.

Comment: I bought two self-powered [USB hubs](http://www.monoprice.com/Product?c_id=103&cp_id=10307&cs_id=1030702&p_id=5328&seq=1&format=2), and plugged in my WiFi adapter, mouse, and keyboard, and I just had the problem occur again. :(

Comment: At the time, my USB harddrive was plugged directly into the computer, not through a self-powered hub. I switched it over, and I'll see if that fixes the problem. Not sure why I hadn't moved it in the first place.